# jQuery back and forth hiding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

HTML Code

```
<div id="sub-up"></div>

<div id="subnavigation">
    <div class="sub-item" data-count="1">
        <a href="#">bla</a>
    </div>                  
    <div class="sub-item" data-count="2">
        <a href="#">bla</a>
    </div>
    <div class="sub-item" data-count="3">
        <a href="#">bla</a>
    </div>
    <div class="sub-item" data-count="4">
        <a href="#">bla</a>
    </div>
    <div class="sub-item" data-count="5">
        <a href="#">bla</a>
    </div>
    <div class="sub-item" data-count="6">
        <a href="#">bla</a>
    </div>
    <div class="sub-item" data-count="7">
        <a href="#">bla</a>
    </div>
    <div class="sub-item" data-count="8">
        <a href="#">bla</a>
    </div>
    <div class="sub-item" data-count="9">
        <a href="#">bla</a>
    </div>
    <div class="sub-item" data-count="10">
        <a href="#">bla</a>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="sub-down"></div>
```

How can I manage it, that, if you load the page, you can see the div's with the `data-count` 1 to 5? When you click on the `sub-down` div you can see the div's with the `data-count` 2 to 6, after another click on the `sub-down` you can see 3 to 7?

When you click on the `sub-up` div, you can see `data-count` 2 to 6 and so on...

I don't know how to remember the position of the 5 shown div's and how to tell jQuery that it has to switch to the highest number, if you want to click lower than `data-count` 1. Like a carrousel effect.

So all I try to accomplish is something like a carrousel with 5 shown div tag's which are moving per click on `sub-down` and `sub-up`.

If you want to read the jQuery Code I coded so far, just tell me. Oh another thing, the `div list is dynamic`.

**SOLUTION** (thx to sdespont)

```
var page = 0;
var pageMax = $('.sub-item').length - 5;

$('#subnavigation div.sub-item').hide().slice(page, page + 5).fadeIn(10);

$('#sub-down').click(function () {
    page = (page < pageMax) ? page+1 : pageMax;
    var tmp = page * 1;
    $('#subnavigation div.sub-item').fadeOut(10).promise().done(function () {
        $('#subnavigation div.sub-item').slice(tmp, tmp + 5).fadeIn(10)
    });
});

$('#sub-up').click(function () {
    page = (page > 0) ? page-1 : 0;
    var tmp = page * 1;
    $('#subnavigation div.sub-item').fadeOut(10).promise().done(function () {
        $('#subnavigation div.sub-item').slice(tmp, tmp + 5).fadeIn(10);
    });
});
```

**EDIT**

Another solution can be found in his/her updated answer. Thank you very much!

Comment: try separate uls and toggle on click?

Comment: @agconti seperate uls? What's that?

Comment: a `ul` is an un-ordered list of `li` (list items) and is the convention for navigational items. look here http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_ul.asp

Comment: @agconti sorry I don't understand how this change could help me regarding the positioning problem.

Comment: include your js. Im suggesting have 3 separate lists at the ranges you specified and show / hiding them with jQuery toggle. The way you have it now, theres no nice way to do it when its all jumbled together.

Comment: @agconti I included what I coded so far, but I'm not sure if this is even the right way to get where I want to, because I don't really have experience in coding with jQuery

Comment: If you want to slide down 1 by 1 all of your li's, consider using css too. Perhaps make a viewport let it position relative and set the ul position absolute. On each click to next set ul position: top -20px or the way you like. That would be much propper and easier.

Comment: @Ghostology This is an option I didn't think of so far. Do I have to use scrollTop() for this?

Comment: Check this out http://jsfiddle.net/ghostology/FZePp/30/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this : http://jsfiddle.net/UQTY2/258/

Play with `nbElem` to chose the number of elements you want to display

```
var $elem = $('#subnavigation div.sub-item');

var page = 0;
var nbElem = 1;
var pageMax = $elem.length / nbElem;
var fadeSpeed = 100;

//Display the first batch of elements
$('#subnavigation div.sub-item').hide().slice(page, page + nbElem).fadeIn(fadeSpeed);

//Next batch of elements
$('#sub-down').click(function () {
    page = (page < pageMax) ? page + 1 : pageMax;
    var tmp = page * nbElem;
    $elem.fadeOut(fadeSpeed).promise().done(function () {
        $elem.slice(tmp, tmp + nbElem).fadeIn(fadeSpeed);
    });
});

//Previous batch of elements
$('#sub-up').click(function () {
    page = (page > 0) ? page - 1 : 0;
    var tmp = page * nbElem;
    $elem.fadeOut(fadeSpeed).promise().done(function () {
        $elem.slice(tmp, tmp + nbElem).fadeIn(fadeSpeed);
    });
});
```

Comment: This looks pretty good, but I don't really understand what you did in here. What do I have to do to slide down 1 by 1 and not 4 at once?

Comment: Code slightly improved

Comment: thank you very much. This helped me a lot. I figured somethin out on my own, which works just the way I wanted it to. :)
Off Topic: Any good tutorials/books to learn javascript/jquery from scratch?

Comment: Just read all the JQuery documentation once. Examples are pretty good to understand what you can do : http://api.jquery.com/

Comment: Thx. I'll look through it. Hopefully I can find something about selectors and syntax in general too.

Answer (score 0):

sdespont's suggestion should work, but have you considered using CSS to show/hide rather than adding and removing your DOM elements?

you could do this with css and nth-child.

```
div.sub-item:nth-child(n+5){
    display: none;
}
```

The result is less javascript, and simpler overall code. 
here's a jsfiddle example.

http://jsfiddle.net/RC4mt/2/